# Get binding column name of templatefield's texbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

In ASP.net, I'm using textbox in templatefield's itemtemplate. I got it data-bound with no problem.
But my problem is, I'm trying to write a function to find column index by its data-bounding table's column name.

Something like this :

```
foreach (DataControlFieldCell cell in row.Cells)
{               
  if (cell.ContainingField is BoundField)
  {
    if (((BoundField)cell.ContainingField).DataField.Equals(SearchColumnName))
    {
      return columnIndex;
    }
  }
  else if (cell.ContainingField is TemplateField)
  {
    //Finding column name of data-bound textbox or dropdownlist ??
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

will this helps you?

```
DataControlFieldCell fieldCell = HeaderRow.Cells[i] as DataControlFieldCell;

DataControlField field = fieldCell.ContainingField;

string strHdrTxt = field.HeaderText.ToString()
```

This one?

string colName = ds.Columns[0].ColumnName;

Comment: Thank you, Bala. But my headertext is usually different from column name.

Answer (score 1):

```
int GetColumIndex(string name)
{
    foreach (DataControlField field in _GridView.Columns)
    {
        if (field.SortExpression == name)
        {
            return _GridView.Columns.IndexOf(field);
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two quick options:

**Option 1**

Put the column name in the SortExpression property of the TemplateField.  You can then access that property to determine the column name.

```
if (((TemplateField)cell.ContainingField).SortExpression.Equals(SearchColumnName))
{ 
    return columnIndex; 
}
```

**Option 2**
Create a custom textbox control derived from the regular textbox control, which includes a `DataField` property.  Set the `DataField` property to the column name when you declare the textbox.  You can later retrieve it by using FindControl on the cell to get a reference to the textbox.